# Spring Hibernate MySQL Test doesn't roll back

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, transactions, rollback

I have a problem with transactional tests using Spring 3.0.5, Hibernate 3 and MySQL 5.
In logs it seems there's everything OK and transaction rolls back, but I got record inserted into database.
My configuration is like this:

```
<bean id="hibernateDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog" />
  <property name="username" value="user" />
  <property name="password" value="password" />
  <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="hibernateDataSource" />
  <property name="schemaUpdate" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>         
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>         
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
      <value>pl.jedenpies.blog.domain.Uzytkownik</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="uzytkownikDao" class="pl.jedenpies.blog.db.hibernate.dao.HibernateUzytkownikDao">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:beans.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class UzytkownikDaoTest {

    private UzytkownikDao uzytkownikDao;

    @Test
    @BeforeTransaction  
    public void test1Config() {
        Assert.notNull(uzytkownikDao, "UzytkownikDao nie moze byc null");
    }

    @Test   
    @Transactional
    @Rollback
    public void test2Create() {
        Uzytkownik u = new Uzytkownik();
        u.setEmail("my4@uzytkownik.pl");
        u.setHaslo("blablabla");
        Assert.isTrue(!u.isIdUstawione());
        u = uzytkownikDao.create(u);
        Assert.notNull(u, "Uzytkownik nie moze byc null");
        Assert.isTrue(u.isIdUstawione());
    }

    @Resource   
    public void setUzytkownikDao(UzytkownikDao uzytkownikDao) {
        this.uzytkownikDao = uzytkownikDao;
    }
}
```

Log:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - executing identity-insert immediately
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - insert into uzytkownicy (email, haslo) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into uzytkownicy (email, haslo) values (?, ?)
DEBUG org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorFactory - Natively generated identity: 43
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener - Method-level @Rollback(true) overrides default rollback [true] for test context [[TestContext@3dbbd23f testClass = UzytkownikDaoTest, locations = array<String>['classpath:beans.xml'], testInstance = pl.jedenpies.blog.dao.UzytkownikDaoTest@22a010ba, testMethod = test2Create@UzytkownikDaoTest, testException = [null]]]
DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@303bc1a1]
DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - rollback
DEBUG org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - rolled back JDBC Connection
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@303bc1a1] after transaction
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
```

Yes, I googled a lot this problem but didn't really find a solution. I have no idea what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: in section 9.3.5.4 of http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx, you are missing some annotations -- like Transactional at the class level, and the tx manager.

Comment: Actually, @Transactional is not needed at the class level, it's enough if it's at the method level.

Comment: Why aren't you sharing your solution if you got one? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I shared it somewhere here. I just was using MyISAM tables, which don't support transactions. By the way, I decided to forget about MySQL and I started to use PostrgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

Do you are using InnoDB engine? MyISAM is the default engine form MySQL 5.x prior to 5.5 and does not support transactions - [Wikipedia - MyISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM)

Comment: Yes! I've just found this solution just minute ago. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following Hibernate property, it conflicts with Spring transaction management:

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that's not the problem.